# Characterizing Difficulty of Integral with Polynomial Integrand

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Math Friends:  I do not need a solution to the below integral - happy to computationally approximate it.  Can you characterize how hard you think it is to get an analytic solution? Is it easy or hard for you to even answer this question?

$$
\mathbb{E}[g(x,y)] = \int_{0}^{100000}\int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\ \frac{3x^2y^2 \times (1-x)}{3125 \times 10^5} \times \left(1 - \frac{y^2}{10^{10}}\right)^7
$$

I am trying to use this as an example motivating Monte Carlo integration, but if the integral is too easy to do analytically, then my choice of example needs improvement.  Thanks for any insight!

Comment: You can write the integral as $\frac{3}{3125 \times 10^5} \: \: \times \: \int x^2(1-x) dx \: \: \times \: \: \int y^2 ( 1- \tfrac{y^2}{10^{10}})^7 dy$, which makes it much easier to solve. In essence it's very easy to explicitly compute the integral, maybe you should find a better example.

Comment: With an appropriate substitution, one has$$3\times2^{10}\times5^{5} \left[\int_0^{\tfrac\pi2} dz \, \sin^2(z) \cos^{15}(z)\right] \left[\int_0^1 dx \, (x^2-x^3)\right]$$and both of the subsequent integrals are standard. (See the second table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Transcendental_functions) for a method for the $z$-integral.)

Comment: Thank you both for the insight, that answers my questions perfectly.